# How to fix error with sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i'm getting this error in my activity

```
05-30 12:19:23.562: E/AndroidRuntime(408): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.SharedPreferences.getStringSet
```

I already tried different suggestion on SO to fix this but i cannot still find where I got a mistake. here is my code:
(on my resume)

```
....
    arraylistUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    arraylistConsumer = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylistConsumerId = new ArrayList<String>();

    arraylistSelectedConsumerIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylistSelectedConsumer = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayListExportedConsumerId = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayListExportedConsumer = new ArrayList<String>();

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_CREATOR, 0);
    sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    exportedConsumerId = new HashSet<String>();
    exportedConsumer = new HashSet<String>();
    exportedConsumerId = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_EXPORTED_CONSUMER_ID, null);
    exportedConsumer = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_EXPORTED_CONSUMER, null);

....
```

and here is the code on my button onclicklistener where i use put string on the sharedpreference

```
....
arraylistUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    arraylistConsumer = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylistConsumerId = new ArrayList<String>();

    arraylistSelectedConsumerIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylistSelectedConsumer = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayListExportedConsumerId = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayListExportedConsumer = new ArrayList<String>();

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_CREATOR, 0);
    sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    exportedConsumerId = new HashSet<String>();
    exportedConsumer = new HashSet<String>();
    exportedConsumerId = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_EXPORTED_CONSUMER_ID, null);
    exportedConsumer = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_EXPORTED_CONSUMER, null);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

getStringSet  method is only support on  API level 11
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29